# Django migrations: base data with tests

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-tests

I am adding some base data to database with Django's database migrations. Base data consists of predefined values of types which are accessible to all users. There is also possibility to create custom types by users.

Problem is that when running tests with `--keepdb` option, tables will be flushed and also base data will be removed. Without `--keepdb` option tests are considerably slower.

Is there a way to create base data so that it would be available to tests with `--keepdb` option? Or is there a way to run tests so that base data would be accessible without doing all migrations again?

---

Migrations I have created look like this:

```
def set_default_values(apps, schema_editor):
    Type = apps.get_model('app1', 'Type')

    Type(name='name1', user=None).save()
    Type(name='name2', user=None).save()
    Type(name='name3', user=None).save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    # ...

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(set_default_values, elidable=True)
    ]
```

Comment: Usually fixtures are used for that.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about fixtures. I must look into that!